# A group of entities aren't updated (Symfony2 & Doctrine)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem with this code:

```
$elements = $em
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:MyElementsEntity')
    ->findByLinkType($linkType); // This returns SEVEN elements

foreach ($elements as $e) {
    $beginDate = $e->getBeginDate();
    $beginDate->setTime($begin->format('H'), $begin->format('i'));
    $endDate = $e->getEndDate();
    $endDate->setTime($end->format('H'), $end->format('i'));

    $e->setEndDate($endDate);
    $e->setBeginDate($beginDate);

    $em->persist($e);
    $em->flush();
}
```

As you can see, it fetches some elements from the database, changes the time from the beginDate and endDate fields ($begin and $end are DateTime objects), and tries to update the database.

The code doesn't throw any exception, but it doesn't work. When I look at Symfony2's log (app/logs/dev.log), there are the SQL statements to fetch the data, alter sessions, etc, but there isn't any update statement.

And I have another function, that only updates one element each time, and this is working correctly.

What I'm doing wrong? Why I can batch-update the previous selected elements? I'm missing something important?

** UPDATE **

I've done some modifications to the code, but it still doesn't update the entities to the database:

- I've removed the `$em->persist($e)` call.
- I've moved the `$em->flush()` call to outside the `foreach` loop.
- I've removed the transactional code (`beginTransaction()`, `commit()` and `rollback()` calls)

But the problem is still the same: Doctrine doesn't send any UPDATE statement to the server (FYI, is an Oracle 11g).

Comment: 1. Why not to call that function which works? 2. You don't need to persist the already managed entities. Remove `$em->persist($e);`, only flush the changes in your update methods.

Comment: @xurshid29 the function that works uses different business logic; they aren't doing the same, so I can't call it. At the beginning there was the `$em->persist($e)`, I've added it to see if this the entities where updated, but it doesn't work...

Comment: do you using transactions?

Comment: @mHouses Your code looks fine, are you sure `$elements` variable holds objects?

Comment: @Trone Yes, I'm using transactions. There is a `$em->getConnection()->beginTransaction()` before the `findByLinkType()` call, and a `$em->getConnection()->commit()` after some checks after the `foreach` loop. I'll try to remove the transaction, and I'll post what happened.

Comment: @xurshid29 Yes, I've done the good old `die(var_dump($e))` between the `persist` and the `flush` calls, and the content is correct.

Comment: i think that `rollback()`  is making problems, try to catch exception in your code and throw it

Comment: @Trone I've removed all the transactions code (`beginTransaction()`, `commit()` and `rollback()`) and it's still not working (there is no change in the queries sent to the server)

Comment: @mHouses Is there any parallell procceses which call `clear()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the people for your help. Finally, I've found the problem.

The problem is with the way Doctrine looks if an entity is dirty or not. He only looks for changes in the scalar fields (strings, numbers, etc), but not in the fields that are objects (another entities, **DateTime objects**, etc).

In the above fragment of code I was only modifying the content of the DateTime objects (`$e->beginDate` and `$e->endDate`), but without creating new objects. This way, Doctrine didn't notice that there where changes in the entity. The solution to avoid this is really easy:

```
foreach ($elements as $e) {
    $beginDate = clone $e->getBeginDate();
    $beginDate->setTime($begin->format('H'), $begin->format('i'));
    $endDate = clone $e->getEndDate();
    $endDate->setTime($end->format('H'), $end->format('i'));

    $e->setEndDate($endDate);
    $e->setBeginDate($beginDate);

    $em->flush();
}
```

Notice the `clone` keyword when initializing the `$beginDate` and `$endDate` temporary variables: they aren't references to the `$e->beginDate` and `$e->endDate` members, but copies of them. Then, when you assign again the new values to the entity, the objects are new, and Doctrine now knows that these entities are dirty.

Answer (score 0):

What is you intention with the loop? I does not seam to do anything... Doctrine will not execute a update query if the entity is not changed (dirty).

```
$elements = $em
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:MyElementsEntity')
    ->findByLinkType($linkType); // This returns SEVEN elements

foreach ($elements as $e) {
    // $beginDate is a \DateTime
    $beginDate = $e->getBeginDate();
    $beginDate->setTime(8, 15);
    $endDate = $e->getEndDate();
    $endDate->setTime(9, 39);
}

$em->flush();
```

**Why your loop does not do anything:**

```
$begin = $e->getBeginDate();
// $begin = 2015-05-18 14:02:00
// $begin->format('H') // will return 14
// $begin->format('i') // will return 02 

$begin->setTime($begin->format('H'), $begin->format('i'));
// $begin is still 2015-05-18 14:02:00
```

Comment: Beware: `$e->getBeginDate()` fetch a date from the database, and `$begin` is a date passed to the service, so `$e` (the entity) is dirty. Why I know this? Because I've var_dumped `$e`, and one of the fields (`$endDate` in my tests) is changed.

Comment: Aside this, I can't put the `$em->flush()` call outside the `foreach` loop because I need to do some checks after persisting the entity to the database (I know, the checks should be done **before** persisting, but I'm converting an old Symfony 1.4 codebase to Symfony 2... Refactoring will be done in the future, I hope...)